# How to fix syntax error with UPDATE in SQLite3 Python module

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update

I'm using python module sqlite3 as per the below code:

```
# Enter the randomised data into the dictionary:
for square in cube:
    cur.execute("UPDATE cubes SET ? = ? WHERE id = ?", (square, cube[square], session["current_cube_id"]))
con.commit()
```

Which results in the following error:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE cubes SET ? = ? WHERE id = ?", (square, cube[square], session["current_cube_id"]))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

I don't seem to have a problem with INSERT or SELECT queries, so I assume there is a specific syntax required to UPDATE.  From the documentation, tutorials and other examples I can find this seems to be correct - can anyone please assist with what might be the syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define table, column names, or SQL keywords, using bind variables (the `SET ? =`) in `UPDATE cubes SET ? = ? WHERE id = ?`

I am not sure why you feel you need to have a dynamic column name, rather than `UPDATE cubes SET mycol = ? WHERE id = ?` but you need to specify your column name differently.

You'd have the exact same problem with insert or delete if your target column names, in an insert, or your where condition column names in a delete, were getting specified with `?` placeholders.  I assume you did not do this so you did not get the error.

Be very careful if you decide to build your query string dynamically as in

```
myquery = f"UPDATE cubes SET {my_user_supplied_column_name} = ? WHERE id = ?"

cur.execute(myquery, (cube[square], session["current_cube_id"]))
```

That opens you to a large class of extremely serious vulnerabilities, the [SQL Injections](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) because the user may enter anything they want in `my_user_supplied_column_name`.  Best to be very careful as it also has a reputational risk: a savvy prospective employer might for example reject your application if they saw this type of construct, unguarded, in your code because it is an extremely grave, frequent and well-known risk.

Comment: I need to iterate through 54 columns; if I have understood correctly using your suggestion would need this repeated 54 times? Could you suggest how you would iterate through 54 columns please? FYI, I have so far used the CS50 module to learn and this worked while using the CS50 module, but in trying to 'remove the crutches' this is now not working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, very helpful - noted re Injection attacks.  When iterating through a large number of columns, is there a better/safer way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You can cycle through your own hardcoded list of column names and sub them in as I showed in the SQL Injection example.  As long as you control the column names yourself, in your code, the risk is fairly minimal.  Make a comment next to it that the variables are not user supplied.  Note that even reading column names from a file is an attack vector, if the file, apparently "just data", is compromised.  Finally, having to cycle through 54 column names seems like a bit of a questionable design approach to the database design, but I can't say without seeing what your table structure looks like.